# Loading multiple iframes with one button?

Tags: iframe

1. I have a HTML page with multiple iframes and i want to load them with 1 button.
2. how can i set height of an iframe so it can adjust according to data, i don't want to fix the height.

Answer (score 0):

You can invoke a javascript function that creates 2 iframes with the properties you want.

such as;

```
function createIFrames(frNo){
    var aFrame = document.createElement("iframe");
    aFrame.setAttribute("id", "frame_" + frNo);
    aFrame.style.height = "100px";
    ...
    ...
    document.body.appendChild(aFrame);
}
```

if you want to change the height or width later with another button you can use a resize function;

```
function createIFrames(frNo){
    var myFrame = document.getElementById("iframe_" + frNo);
    myFrame.style.height = "200px";
    ...
    ...
}
```